# In Python, how could I shell out and interact with an external program (say vi or nano) and return to python

Tags: python, python-interactive

My first question on stackoverflow!

I'm trying to figure out how I can start an external program that requires the user to interact with it, say vi, nano, ssh, telnet etc. and return to the Python script when the program exits.

I don't want to use send/expect or automate the external program at all, just start it, use it as normal and then return to the script.  I guess bash seems like a more natural way to do this, but I was hoping to get it done in Python.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Read the second paragraph.  He doesn't want to interact with it; he wants to pass it straight to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the integrated [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). It works quite well with interactive applications. `subprocess.call` starts an application and is blocking until the application exits.

e.g. starting `vi` and after exit it starts a connection to 127.0.0.1 over `ssh`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["vi"])
subprocess.call(["ssh","127.0.0.1"])
```

Comment: I tested this solution with vim, ssh, telnet, nano and bash. It works quite well!

Comment: Thats works perfectly.  Many thanks.

Comment: is there anyway to do this when writing to stdin through a subprocess.popen? e.g. subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) and then when I run something interactive it (I dont mean literally) "switches to .call" and back

Answer (score -1):

You can use the subprocess module.
An example could look like this:

```
import subprocess

process = subproces.Popen(
    [
        'path/to/the/executable',
        'optional argument',
        'more optional arguments',
        ...
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

You can find more here: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess)